# Django Migration error due to auth_user field not existing

Tags: python, django, django-custom-user

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
```

this is the error that I'm getting I'm using PostgreSQL as my database here is my connection to the database

```
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME' : 'listeners',
        'USER' : 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD' : '***********',
        'HOST' : 'localhost'
    }
}
```

this is my models:

```
 from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from flask_login import user_accessed


class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, phone_number, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email address")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("User must have a username")

        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            phone_number = phone_number
        )
        user.is_admin = False
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
def create_superuser(self, first_name, email, username, password):
    user = self.create_user(
        email = self.normalze_email(email),
        username  = username,
        pasword = password,
        first_name = first_name,
        last_name = last_name,
        )
    user.is_admin  =    True
    user.is_active =    True
    user.is_staff  =    True
    user.is_superuser = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name    = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username     = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    email        = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True)
    date_joined  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active    = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

USERNAME_FIELD =  'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username','first_name','last_name']

objects = MyAccountManager()


def _str_(self):
    return self.email

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    return self.is_admin

def has_module_perms(self, add_label):
    return True
```

I have tried looking for similar posts and I did migrate each individual app and did use `python manage.py migrate auth`
What could be the problem I'm facing or what could I be doing wrong
(I have not actually wrote all of this but instead Copied most of the code from another resource and this is not for anything else but for me to learn this is not some kind of commercial project or something this is something I'm doing to learn django)
Do I have an issue with my connection to my database but all of my models have been registered in my database table This is a custom user model in django and I'm using this to add new fields to my database do I just make another table called auth_user by myself? or should I restart all of my project?

Comment: Have you set AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using a new database instead of starting project all over.  When you need custom user table you will have to make changes regarding it in admin.py, models.py and settings.py(set AUTH_USER_MODEL) . Then run makemigrations and migrate command.You will see in database that no auth_user table will be there and your custom table will appear which django will use as auth_user table.